# Update multiple SQL connection strings in an Excel macro

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have an Excel document with several (50+) embedded SQL queries that get refreshed and update counts and query results. I need to change the server and the database that these queries run from and I was hoping there was a simpler way to do this than manually typing everything in. I have searched through some of the other questions here but I was unable to find something that matched what I am looking to do.

Most of my connection strings look like this:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=ServerName;UID=ThisisMe;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=CEPC098JJN
```

What I need to add also, is the database which I believe looks like this:

```
Initial Catalog=DatabaseName
```

Any guidance on next steps on how to update all these connection strings is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My personal opinion would be to create a file outside of the application and read from the file to get the connection string.In that way you wont in the future have to deal with this again.

Comment: @Miguel - like an ODBC system or file dsn...?

Comment: @Jeeped Kinda, but a bit more crude, since this is vba, you can technically, think of the file as a config file and even have like       `dbname-values`  and in that way you can simple retrieve the file, find the name and use that as your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should use a text file to store the values ​​as suggested by Miguel. In the application, load values ​​into the dictionary, so they will be convenient and easy to use. For example:

```
Sub test()
Dim d, key
    Set d = FileLoad("c:\soft\1.txt")
    For Each key In d.Keys
        Debug.Print ("key = " & key & " Value = " & d(key))
    Next key
End Sub


Function FileLoad(path As String) As Variant
Dim str, arr, dict
Open path For Input As #1
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, str
    arr = Split(str, ":")
    dict.Add arr(0), arr(1)
Loop
Close #1
Set FileLoad = dict
End Function
```

Text file like:
Initial Catalog:DatabaseName

And replace this values in strings...

Answer (score 0):

use Find and Replace and select Entire Project.

Something like

```
Find: UID=ThisisMe;
Replace: UID=ThisisMe;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;
```